# Officejs calls fail with 7000 Permission Denied for new file

Tags: office365, office-js, office365-apps

I have Office Apps add-in (word/excel/pp) with `ReadWriteDocument` permissions.

However there is unexplained behavior when I open a new file, open my add-in and try call either `Office.context.document.getFilePropertiesAsync` or `Office.context.document.getFileAsync`. Both calls return 7000 Permission Denied as response.

Firstly I figured it's because file is empty, however even when I add some content to the file and save it, behavior is the same. I have to refresh whole page in order for above methods to work.

Do I need to refresh the context? If yes, how can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just tried the methods in all clients and this is not failing anymore. issue fixed.